# Using throw for user defined exception

Tags: java, exception, throw

Following is the code where " throw use; " shows an error.Why? How to use throw for user defined exceptions?Give some example?

```
class use extends Exception{
public String toString() {
    return "too many exceptions";
}
}   
class user{
public static void main(String s[]) {
    int i=3;
    try {
        if(i>1)
            throw use;
    }
    catch(use e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("program executed successfully!");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need an instance of the exception class to throw it:

```
throw new use();
```

or

```
use a = new use();
throw a;
```

In the future please follow Java naming conventions, it will make your code much more readable. (class names should start with a capital letter).

Answer (score 0):

User defined exceptions can be created and thrown in Java.

By inheriting the Exception class you can create your own exceptions.

And it can be thrown as and when required

Following example shows how to create and throw user defined exceptions

http://www.csnotes32.com/2014/09/how-to-create-user-defined-exception-in.html

Answer (score 0):

And remember, you don't need to roll your own.

```
throw new RuntimeException("Do not instantiate this class");
```

(old question, but I always forget syntax, so stashing on google)